# adding file extension in a redirecting form

Tags: php

I'm going to use a basic form to redirect to pages which i will define upon which value is entered

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['bt']))
{
header("Location: http://mysite/" . $_POST['folder']);
}
?>
<html>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="folder" id="folder" />
<input type="submit" name="bt" id="bt" value="Go To" />
</form>
</html>
```

This results in redirects to http://mysite/whateverwasentered

without a file extension.

My question is just how/where in this code could a file extension (.php) be added so the result is http://mysite/whateverwasentered.php ?

Answer (score 2):

you can add it simply in the end of your string to the header function like this:

```
header("Location: http://mysite/" . $_POST['folder'].".php");
```

Answer (score 1):

Trim it as well on the safe side

```
  $pageLink = trim($_POST['folder']).".php";
  header("Location: http://mysite/" .$pageLink );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
header("Location: http://mysite/" . $_POST['folder'] . ".php");
```

This will add '.php' behind `$_POST['folder']`.

Comment: @DesBank Is this what you're looking for?